# How to fetch First Name Last Name using Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Fetch customer details using query or object manager

Want to display the following fields

> First Name Last Name Email telephone State /region pincode

Comment: You can try this code. If you have any issue then you can tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$customerId = 3;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
$customerAddress = array();

//Get all customer Data
var_dump($customerObj->getData());

foreach ($customerObj->getAddresses() as $address)
{
    $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
}

//Here you will get Customer Address data like region, city etc.
foreach ($customerAddress as $customerAddres) {

    echo $customerAddres['street'];
    echo $customerAddres['city'];
}
```

Thanks